# Form request in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

1.How to deal with question mark in form request in laravel ?

2.Should I set the default value each input tag ?

**create.blade.php**

```
<form class="form-horizontal row-fluid" name="user_input_form" action="/bonds" method="POST">
  @csrf
  <p><strong>Apply</strong></p>
  <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">investment</label>
      <div class="controls">
          <div class="input-append">
              <input type="text" name="investment" id="investment" placeholder="" class="w-full span12">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">investment_name</label>
      <div class="controls">
          <div class="input-append">
              <input type="text" name="investment_name" id="investment_name" placeholder="" class="span12">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">i_id</label>
      <div class="controls">
          <div class="input-append">
              <input type="text" name="i_id" id="i_id" placeholder="" class="span12">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">price</label>
      <div class="controls">
          <div class="input-append">
              <input type="text" value="" name="price" id="price" placeholder="" class="span12" onchange="getagreement();"><span class="add-on"></span>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**BondsController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

      $bond = Bond::create([
          'investment' => request('investment'),
          'investment_name' => request('investment_name'),
          'i_id' => request('i_id'),
          'price' => request('price'),
          'p_goal' => request('p_goal'),
          'c_date' => request('c_date'),
          'c_date2' => request('c_date2'),
          'c_date3' => request('c_date3'),
          'agreement' => request('agreement'),
          'goal_in' => request('goal_in'),
...
}
```

**The Error Like This**

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'investment' cannot be null 
>   (SQL: insert into `bonds` (`investment`, `investment_name`, `i_id`, `price`, `p_goal`, `c_date`, `c_date2`, `c_date3`, `agreement`, `goal_in`, `goal_out`, `c_date4`, `invest_date`, `p_price`, `t_price`, `contract`, `c_date5`, `confirm1`, `confirm2`, `confirm3`, `confirm4`, `confirm5`, `law_office`, `etc`, `address`, `phone`, `birth`, `email`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
>    values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 27.5, ?, 1, ?, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 2020-01-26 04:02:42, 2020-01-26 04:02:42))

Comment: It means `request('investment'),` is null

Comment: @TsaiKoga 
Thanks for answer ! 
What should I do to null request ?

Comment: you can use validator, or give a default value.

Comment: @TsaiKoga 

You mean like this ?

$request->validate([
    'investment' => 'nullable'
]);

Comment: It is validator, but not nullable. I will post my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `request('investment')` is nullable, however your field `investment` in `bonds` cannot be nullable. So you can use validator to check the fields.Or
set the default value in this field.

#### Use validator:

try to use [validator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation) like this:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $this->validate($request, [
          'investment' => 'required',
          ...
      ]);


      $bond = Bond::create([
          ....
}
```

#### Set default value:

```php
$bond = Bond::create([
   'investment' => $request->input('invenstment', 'your_default_value');
   ...
]);
```

#### Change the field to nullable:

```php
$table->string('investment')->nullable();
```

Comment: Thank you so much your help :)         

But It seems to not working right .. ( Data had not put in to DataBase.. )         
 
Can I show you my updated code ?

Comment: @DropDtuning because the validator find the investment is nullable, so it just return fail, and not put datas in database.

Comment: @DropDtuning if you still want to create the datas without value, you can set the default value or just change your field to nullable in database.

Comment: @TsaiaKoga Thanks for answer !! I changed my field to nullable , and It works very well